# Cocoa Touch library with UIApplication and UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, library-project

WebView google site is not loaded in this scenario

[image]

While we tried to use , its get loaded...

[image]

Can anyone guide me how to make the first code to be worked inside cocoa touch library project

Comment: try with https instead of http or modify your transport security to allow http

Comment: i have tried with https but can't get the webview to be loaded...can you suggest me any?

Comment: add `web.layer.borderWidth = 1` and `web.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor red] CGcolor]`and let me know if you see a red rectangle on your app

Comment: when i used     [self.view addSubview:web]; its displayed but when i tried to use [app.keyWindow addSubview: web]; its not displayed

Comment: try NSLog(@"%@",app.keyWindow) and let me know what prints

Comment: (null) value getting displayed

Comment: is more than obvious that the main problem is not the `UIWebView` load is instead that you are adding the `UIWebView` in a nill view, so you can post all your code where you put your `UIWebView` inside your `window`???

Comment: Then how to add UIWEbview in     UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegates to achieve webview from static library to application

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    // UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIWebView *web=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    web.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    web.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
   // NSURLRequest * req = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.yahoo.com"]];

  [web loadRequest:req];
 [self.adView addSubview:web];
```

Concentrate on adView ... here you will get stuck...

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to add the `UIWebView` to App key Window, your issue was that maybe where you are using your code the self.view is nil, I suppose

```
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIWebView* web = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, app.keyWindow.frame.size.width, app.keyWindow.frame.size.height)];
web.layer.borderWidth = 1;
web.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
NSURLRequest * req = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.w3schools.com"]];
[web loadRequest:req];
[app.keyWindow addSubview:web];
```

Hope this helps, for me work as should

Comment: @sugansoft my answer is there from july 13 so, why is not the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
 UIWebView *web=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

web.layer.borderWidth = 1;
web.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```

[web loadRequest:req];
   [self.adView addSubview:web];